# jQuery focus on Alert box with clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, after submitting form when button is clicked using jQuery like this.

```
function validate(){
   if($('#firstname').val() =="")
           alert("Please enter your first name");
   else if($('#lastname').val() == "")
    alert("Please enter your last name");
   else if( $('#association').val() == "")
    alert("Choose your association");
   else if($('#association_no').val() == "")
    alert("Please enter your association number");
   else
    $('#register').submit();
  }


  $(function(){


       $(".enter_submit").keyup(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 13) 
        validate();

      })

  })
```

The alert box is displaying fine but my issue that When I press enter after alert box is displayed, it gives another alert box instead of getting rid of the alert(Works fine when I click OK with mouse). In FF, it gives #prevent more alerts from this page. So I believe its still focusing on the form even after alert is displayed.

Comment: `alerts` are annoying. Get rid of it and instead show message some other way. What is `.enter_submit`?

Comment: I agree but I'm curious how to fix it in this situation. .enter_submit is a class, which if u add to any text field will submit the form when enter is pressed when the cursor is in that text field.

Answer (score 0):

Specify return False after the alert box is displayed. This might not show other alert box at the same time.

```
function validate() {
            if ($('#firstname').val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter your first name");
                return false;
            }
            else if ($('#lastname').val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter your last name");
                return false;
            }
            else if ($('#association').val() == "") {
                alert("Choose your association");
                return false;
            }
            else if ($('#association_no').val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter your association number");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#register').submit();
                return true;
            }
        }


        $(function () {
            $(".enter_submit").keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13)
                    return validate();
            });
        });
```

Hope this help

Thanks
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using blur function

```
  $(".enter_submit").keyup(function(event) {
        $(this).blur();
         if(event.keyCode === 13) 
        return validate();

      })
```

I figured that the text field was still on focus even when the alert was being displayed so had to take it out of focus i.e, blur it. Thanks to everyone who replied.